# Getting JSON from a REST endpoint with axios - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, python, json, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to parse a json list from a endpoint on my react app. But json is recognized as string, and when I use the spread operator  , the result is spreading each character. From the server side, I received the json from a database and I simply use the `json.dumps()` to the endpoint. The interesting fact is that already work for a long time but I don't know why this fails now. I tried to use `JSON.parse()` but the received object is a invalid input and then, I also turned to the server, but there when I read the response (python) is perfectly readable as list of dicts before dumping it (I also, tried `jsonify()`, adding the list into a dict and etc..).  If I sent only one object, `json.dumps(list[0])`, it's possible to see the dict as object on the react side.

The endpoint data:
[image: json response]

```json
[{"n": {"altitude": [110, 110], "subtype": "", "name": "Alqueva", "location": [-7.49623775, 38.19746677, 110.0], "fwl": 152, "block": "", "id": "0", "tag": "origin", "power": 520, "type": "Barragem", "tia": 0}}, {"n": {"altitude": [0, 0], "subtype": "", "name": "Alamos", "block": "", "location": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], "fwl": 227.5, "id": "1", "tag": "distribution", "power": 0, "type": "Barragem", "tia": 0}}, {"n": {"altitude": [0, 0], "subtype": "", "name": "Loureiro", "location": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], "fwl": 220, "block": "", "id": "2", "tag": "distribution", "power": 0, "type": "Barragem", "tia": 0}}, ...
```

The javascript/react code:

```js
loadNeo4jAPI = async () => {
    await axios.get("http://192.xxx.xx.xxx:5001/api/waternode").then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;
      this.setState({ waternodes: [...data] });
      console.log("nodes", this.state.waternodes);
    });
    this.forceUpdate();
  };
```

The result:
[image: react read]

```js
App.js:43 nodes 
(111214) ["[", "{", """, "n", """, ":", " ", "{", """, "a", "l", "t", "i", "t", "u", "d", "e", """, ":", " ", "[", "1", "1", "0", ",", " ", "1", "1", "0", "]", ",", " ", """, "s", "u", "b", "t", "y", "p", "e", """, ":", " ", """, """, ",", " ", """, "n", "a", "m", "e", """, ":", " ", """, "A", "l", "q", "u", "e", "v", "a", """, ",", " ", """, "l", "o", "c", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", """, ":", " ", "[", "-", "7", ".", "4", "9", "6", "2", "3", "7", "7", "5", ",", " ", "3", "8", ".", "1", "9", "7", "4", "6", …]
```

There is a proof that axios receive a content type json:
[image: axios response]

Comment: use JSON.parse before data or check your api why it returns string instead of json array.
{ waternodes: [...JSON.parse (data)] }

Comment: @Eric , as I said in the text, the `JSON.parse(data)` fails : `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 27570 ` . but I used now a json linter (https://jsonlint.com/), and the problem can be the `NaN` values. I will test

Comment: make sure your backend api returns a valid json. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solution] The JSON file contained `NaN` values, and since it was not a string, the json becomes invalid. I figured out that  using an online version of a json linter.Thanks also to @Eric